# RTPostgis Library fail at Make Check

Tags: postgresql, postgis, libxml2, gdal, geos

I'm trying to compile the latest stable PostGis's version or the SVN's version and both fails at **Make Check** when adding the Raster support.

At error log i see this message, what I found nothing in internet about it.

```
psql:/usr/src/postgis-sources/postgis-2.0.1/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis/rtpostgis.sql:48: 
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/src/postgis-sources/postgis-2.0.1/regress/00-regress-install/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": /usr/src/postgis-sources/postgis-2.0.1/regress/00-regress-install/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK11xercesc_2_710XMLRefInfo14isSerializableEv
```

I did compile with:

#### ./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config && make && make install

My configs are:
--OS: Centos 5.8 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 32 bits

--PostgreSQL 9.2.1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704

--Postgis 2.0.1 - r9979 - 2012-11-09 18:40:01

--GEOS: 3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5

--PROJ: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012

--GDAL: 1.9.2**

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Andrey Cassemiro

Answer (score 1):

Why not just install from prebuilt binaries? See instructions to install from [PGDG RPMs with YUM](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20CentOS6pgdg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm running Centos 5.8 and couldn't find PostGis there http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-5.8-i386. I think that the best thing to do is upgrade my CentOS version.